# Can't connect to mongo with Clozure CL - cl-mongo

Tags: mongodb, common-lisp, clozure-cl

**Update 3**: *this applies to Clozure Common Lisp*. 
*I subsequently tried this in SBCL, and it worked without a problem, using latest mongo-community.*

I'm following the book [Lisp for the Web](https://www.adamtornhill.com/articles/lispweb.htm) which has been going well. Now I've reached the section which uses mongodb, with which I have limited experience. I'm not succeeding at connecting to mongo from CCL using [cl-mongo](https://github.com/fons/cl-mongo). I have `mongodb-community` installed via `brew` and the `mongodb/brew` tap as per [instructions](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew) and issuing `mongo` at the command line takes me to the mongo shell so it does seem installed OK.

But from CCL attempting to connect I get this:

(Strangely when I issue `(db.use "test")` it always fails with connection refused the first time, then doesn't complain the second time when issued 'within an error', as below).

*(I'm not at all clear about what issuing expressions 'within an error' really means, or what one could sensibly do there - any help on that would be great, including how to learn more about this).*

```lisp
CCL is free software.  It is distributed under the terms of the Apache
Licence, Version 2.0.
? (ql:quickload '(:cl-mongo))
To load "cl-mongo":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-mongo
; Loading "cl-mongo"

(:CL-MONGO)
? (use-package :cl-mongo)
T
? (db.use "test")
> Error: Error #<USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR #x30200262ED9D>
> While executing: USOCKET::RAISE-ERROR-FROM-ID, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
1 > (db.use "test")
"test"
1 > (db.insert "foo" (kv "document" "one"))
error occured when sending message : There is no applicable method for the generic function:
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION USOCKET:SOCKET-STREAM #x30200244649F>
when called with arguments:
  (NIL)
closing connection (type-of MONGO) [name : DEFAULT ] 
 {[id : 9FB20354-9DFF-41E5-B2C6-737F0D7D2FB0] [port : 27017] [host : localhost] [db : test]} 


 unable to close mongo connection for mongo connection (type-of MONGO) [name : DEFAULT ] 
 {[id : 9FB20354-9DFF-41E5-B2C6-737F0D7D2FB0] [port : 27017] [host : localhost] [db : test]} 
: error There is no applicable method for the generic function:
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION USOCKET:SOCKET-CLOSE #x30200244095F>
when called with arguments:
  (NIL)
NIL
1 >
```

This is what I get when I type `mongo` in the shell

```sh
mbp:lispforweb m$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("acd39568-e862-4a2d-8dcf-45409f11e029") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.1
Server has startup warnings: 
2019-11-17T23:02:18.194+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-11-17T23:02:18.194+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-11-17T23:02:18.194+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-11-17T23:02:18.194+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---

> exit
bye
mbp:lispforweb m$
```

**Update**: I could not connect using an older version of Robo3T I had on my system, till I upgraded it to the latest version, to reflect mongo v4.x. Since cl-mongo hasn't been touched in a few years, perhaps it is not compatible with mongodb v.4.x?  (a guess).

**Update 2**: I downgraded mongo to mongodb-community@3.2, and I get the same problem. An [issue](https://github.com/fons/cl-mongo/issues/32) on the github page of mongo-cl suggests mongo-cl is not compatible with mongodb > v.3.0, and no version below 3.2 appears supported any more (available on the mongo brew tap). 3.2 is the oldest available.

Comment: You might need to start the service, akin to `services start mongodb-community` or just `mongod`: https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew#starting-the-mongodb-community-server

Comment: i've done that. it's running. (`brew services start mongodb-commununity` & `brew services list`)

Comment: you seem to work one and two levels deep in error loops? why?

Comment: @RainerJoswig yes, you're right. I'm coming from `clisp` and didn't notice that. Expecting line numbers. I've updated the output above.

Comment: @mwal: problem is that you are then still within an error and leaving this to the top-level might then call some clean-up code like closing things etc - which otherwise would be left open and have side-effects

Comment: @RainerJoswig Why does issuing `(db.use "test")` the second time simply return "test"?